# Getting all keys with highest value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, max

In python dictionary, how to search the max value and return the key of the max value in a list. For instance, 3 is the max value in this dictionary.
Given:

Frequency = {9: 3, 2: 3, 6: 2, 8: 1, 1: 1}
Output: [9, 2]

```
def max_value(dict):
    for key, value in dict.items():
    max_value = max(dict.values())
    new_list = []
    if frequency[key] == max_value:
        new_list.append(key)
    return new_list
```

With this function, I can only get one key inside the new_list. I am expecting to get [9, 2]

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the shown code. (2) Better don't use built-in names like `dict` for variables.

Comment: `new_list = []` creates a new list each time. `return new_list` ends the function. Hard to say which is the problem because the indentation in your question is messed up.

Comment: @OsmanMamun Your suggestion will work but is very inefficient as *max()* will be invoked once for every key in the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the max value before the for loop:

```
def keys_with_max_value(d: dict[int, int]) -> list[int]:
    max_value = max(d.values())
    max_value_keys = []
    for key, value in d.items():
        if value == max_value:
            max_value_keys.append(key)
    return max_value_keys
```

**Example Usage:**

```
frequency = {9: 3, 2: 3, 6: 2, 8: 1, 1: 1}
print(keys_with_max_value(frequency))  # Output: [9, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the maximum value once then use a list comprehension with a condition to generate the list:

```
def kmv(d):
    _max = max(d.values())
    return [k for k, v in d.items() if v == _max]

myDict = {
    9: 3,
    2: 3,
    6: 2,
    8: 1,
    1: 1
    }

print(kmv(myDict))
```

**Output:**

```
[9, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could track the maximum value as you go and obtain the result in a sinle pass through the data:

```
def maxKeys(d):
    result = []
    for k,v in d.items():
         if not result or v > maxVal:
            result, maxVal = [k] ,v
         elif v == maxVal:
            result.append(k)
    return result
```

output:

```
d = {9: 3, 2: 3, 6: 2, 8: 1, 1: 1}

print(maxKeys(d)) # [9, 2]
```